# Where to add HTML5 tags?

Tags: html, header

Let's say you want to use a `<header>` tag for the header part of your site.

But currently your header is made from 3 elements (because of design-related reasons), like:

```
<div id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header-content">

      ...

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So which one of these DIVs should be replaced with `<header>` ? And does it matter?

Comment: It depends on what you're using each component for. Are all three classes needed by a stylesheet? Can you find a way to have fewer elements that works with your design? You may have to rename classes a little or move stuff around.

Comment: All three. If you're nesting `div` elements this way, you're (probably) doing it wrong.

Comment: But why? How can I do it differently if I need 3 background images to build the header?

Comment: @Alex All browsers (except IE8) support [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) `:)`

Comment: But I need the site to look nice on uncool browsers too, like IE 8 and maybe IE 7 :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A purpose of HTML5's new tags is to add semantic meaning to your document. On the other hand, generic elements like `<div>` have been preserved precisely because they have *no* semantic meaning. They are ideal for adding visual structure without impacting the semantic structure.

The `<header>` element should envelop the semantic header. I would venture to say it's most likely the outermost element that should be `<header>` since all elements involved clearly exist to support the header in some fashion, but only you know the semantic meaning of your document best, so you can best answer specifically.